# Active Model Serializer with different serializer for each model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm using ActiveModelSerializer 0.10. I have a collection of `Account`s that I want to serialize. Is there some way to set a specific serializer for each model in the collection? I want my controller to return something like this:

```
{"accounts":
  [
    {"type":"Group","groupname":"A group","internal_info":"Sensitive info"},
    {"type":"User","first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Smith","internal_info":"Sensitive info"}
  ]
}
```

My API is divided into two parts: a user API and an admin API. The user API uses the standard serializers which ActiveModelSerializer finds automatically. Something like this

```
render json: @accounts
```

would return this (note that sensitive information is not included):

```
{"accounts":
  [
    {"type":"Group","groupname":"A group"},
    {"type":"User","first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Smith"}
  ]
}
```

The admin API uses custom serializers (they includes more details, for instance the `internal_info`). How can I render such a collection in my admin API? I know I can use

```
render json: @accounts, each_serializer: Admin::AccountSerializer
```

which works perfectly in most cases, but in this particular case I have two types of `Account`s. Can I somehow use `Admin::Account::GroupSerializer` for `Group` objects in the collection and `Admin::Accounts::UserSerializer` for `User` objects in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `Admin::AccountSerializer` and conditions. Better solutions are welcome.

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :groupname, if: :a_group?

  attribute :first_name, if: :a_user?
  attribute :last_name, if: :a_user?

  def a_group?
    object.class == Group
  end

  def a_user?
    object.class == User
  end
end
```